# Edit user keeps adding new one to the database

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to edit my users but my app keeps adding new ones to the database when trying to save the updates.
Can anyone guide me on how can I update the users with a form table?

Form table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="/webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
    <div>
        <h1>Edit User</h1>
    </div>

<form th:action="@{/users/save}" method="post"
      style="max-width:600px; margin: 0 auto;"
      th:object="${user}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{user.id}"/>
    <div class="m-3">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-4">Username</label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{username}"
                       required minlength="5" maxlength="30"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-4">Password</label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input th:value="${user.password}" class="form-control" th:field="*{password}"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-4">Enabled</label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="checkbox"  th:field="*{enabled}"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-4">Roles</label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <th:block th:each="role:${roleList}">
                <input type="checkbox"  th:field="*{user.roles}"
                       th:value="${role.id}"
                       th:text="${role.name}" class="m-2"/>
                </th:block>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller

```
import com.florin.restaurant.role.Role;
import com.florin.restaurant.service.IUserDetailsService;
import com.florin.restaurant.service.RoleService;
import com.florin.restaurant.user.MyUserDetails;
import com.florin.restaurant.user.User;
import com.florin.restaurant.util.AttributeNames;
import com.florin.restaurant.util.Mappings;
import com.florin.restaurant.util.ViewNames;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Path;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EditUserController {

    private final IUserDetailsService userService;
    private final RoleService roleService;




        @PostMapping(value="/users/save")
    public String saveEdit(@Validated @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors() ){
            return "edit-user2";
        }


        return "redirect:/users";
    }



    @GetMapping(Mappings.USERS_ID)
    public String editUser(@PathVariable int id, Model model){
        List<Role> roleList = roleService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("user", userService.findUserById(id));
        model.addAttribute("roleList", roleList);

        return "edit-user2";
    }

@DeleteMapping("/users/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable int id){
            userService.deleteUser(id);
            return ViewNames.REDIRECT+ViewNames.USERS;
}
}
```

I deleted my code since it wasn't working.
Also the checkboxes from the roles did not seem to update the user when I saved it.

Comment: Should you not be using PutControllers to update the information.

Comment: it's irrelevant in this case, won't work with put